# Want to change webhook fulfillment back to inline cloud functions but it won't stick

Tags: actions-on-google

I have a voice dialog project in Google Actions Console, and I initially wanted to specify a custom https endpoint, so that I could trigger some functions I have created in Firebase Cloud Functions.

At this point, I can either go in that direction, except I don't quite know what url to specify, or how exactly to create that endpoint.

So, I thought I could go back to an easier approach, which would be to use the inline code editor, in the Actions Console. I pressed the Change Fulfillment Method to go back to  Inline Cloud Functions. The problem is, that choice doesn't seem to "stick". Any suggestions? Seems like the Actions Console won't let me go back to using inline.

Comment: Hang on, I editing the inline code, to force it to notice that something changed ...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so as far as switching back, that was the key. I checked the inline functions box and then changed something in my code, which I had from before. It woke up, and realized something had changed, and the "stickiness" went away.